# Is capturing better than killing a monster?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

In Monster Hunter World is it better to capture monsters vs kill them if the quest isn't kill specific? By better I mean will it generate more rewards to capture or just different rewards?

Comment: In previous titles capturing was almost *always* the better choice for getting rare drops, but I have not played/seen enough of World to confirm if the same rule applies.

Comment: Comparing investigations of capture vs kill it seems like captures seem to give out more rewards at the end vs being able to carve out a few materials. But in terms of non specific quests/expeditions I can't tell

Comment: Also note that reward from killing requires carving which may be interrupted by nearby monsters especially into higher tier quests where there might be another large monster which is not related to the main quest. This potentially reduces reward for killing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Capturing a monster will always give you more rewards but sometimes also different ones. Personally I'd say capturing a monster is "better" unless you're farming for a very specific item that can only be carved. You can see the rewards of monsters in your hunter's notes and if a certain Item only shows up in the "Carving" tab you won't get it from capturing a monster.

As a quick list: Here are some pros and cons for capturing a monster in MH World.

### Pro

- More rewards than from killing a monster
- Only 20 seconds to return to camp/HQ (the hunt is faster in general since you don't have to completely deplete the monster's health)
- You can usually get "breakable" items even though you didn't break the part of the monster (Tails if you're using a blunt weapon for example)
- Gives you more research points than simply killing it.
- Messing up a trap isn't as bad anymore since you can restock everything in your tent.

### Con

- Requires some setup (Traps, Tranquillizer)
- Requires precision and Knowledge of the monster (When can you capture it?). When normally hunting a monster you can just smash it without much thought about when to stop.
- Some Items may be carve-only (From personal experience Plates, which are very rare, have a higher droprate in carves than in quest-rewards but I don't have any numbers on that)
- The monster needs to be lured towards a specific location. Traps don't work everywhere.

In general I'd say you should capture monsters if you're farming for a specific armor set and if you're still missing some specific items you can go for a normal hunt (only if the drop chance from carving is better of course).

Comment: In MHW there is an option to skip the post victory 20/60 sec and return to town immediately. Though in killing hunts you'd want that time to carve.

Comment: I'd also add another Pro to capturing that the hunt ends faster as you do not need to reduce the monster's HP to 0 before capturing.

Comment: @BenOng Oh I didn't know about the skipping part (Is that in the options somewhere?). I already mentiononed the quicker hunt but I'll clarify it further :)

Comment: The option that is originally abandon mission will change to exit and you can use it to skip post quest timer

Comment: Something to note, after you have captured a monster it will unlock an arena quest where you get to kill it for more resources (on top of what you got when you captured it).